# How to execute only the outer for loop in scala?

Tags: scala, for-loop

In Scala, what if I have a nested for loop, and I want to execute different things on each one.

```
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
   System.out.println(i);       //do something for just i
   for(int j = 0; j<5; j++) {
      System.out.println(i+j);  //do something for both i and j
   }
}
```

But the scala code:

```
for {i<-0  to 5 
     j<- 0 to 5} yield { print(i); print(i+j)}
```

gives the output:

```
    0
(0,0)
0
(0,1)
0
(0,2)
0
(0,3)
0
(0,4)
0
(0,5)
```

but I want it to be:

```
0
(0,0)
(0,1)
(0,2)
(0,3)
(0,4)
(0,5)
```

Is there a way to only print `i` for each `i`, and `i+j` for each `i` and `j` in **ONE** for loop?

Comment: `if (j == 0) print(i); print(i+j);` .. not very clean, as side-effects. Why not just a nested loop? You can still use the "x <- a to b" syntax for the range.

Comment: This is an abstract representation of my problem. Basically I want to iterate through two things, do something on the outer loop and something on the inner loop.@user2864740

Comment: Just use two for-loops. Also, `for{...} {...}` is for-loop. `for{...} yield {...}` is for-comprehension. They are very different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative way of doing the same would be to use `map` function as following

```
val loop = 0 to 5
loop.map(i => {
  println(i) // do your stuffs as you did for i
  loop.map(j => {
    println(i, j) //do your stuffs as you did for i, j 
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

The compiler rewrites `for` comprehensions into their constituent `map()`, `flatMap()`, `foreach()`, and `withFilter()` parts. That's why some of the normal rules of Scala syntax don't apply inside sequence comprehension expressions. They get mangled in the rewriting process.

There are a few tricks to get around the problem.

```
for {
  i <- 0 to 5
  _ = println(i)
  j <- 0 to 5
} yield // do stuff with i and j
```

It really depends on what you need to do with the `i` value. It could be that a `for` comprehension is not the best tool for the job.

Comment: If it's for side effects, like in OP's case, it's probably better to remove `yield`.

Comment: @user2864740; I wrote that "_some_ of the normal rules" don't apply. Here are 2 examples: 1) can't place a `println()` statement (without the trick shown in the above answer). 2) can't create variables in the normal way. (e.g. `val x = 5` won't compile but `x = 5` will) I wasn't trying to say that the OP's code wouldn't execute. It works just fine. But what the OP wants to do, putting code between 2 generators, is tricky at best, and seldom advisable.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick:

```
(0 to 5).zip(0 to 5).foreach{case (i, j) => 
    //do stuff to i an dj
}
```

Comment: This has the same "problem" as the original if the "stuff" is `print(i); print(i+j)`.